# Cookie clicker bot with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a script in python (using Selenium) that, when you run it, opens a browser, goes to the [Cookie clicker website](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) and starts clicking. That part works fine but I tried to implement a feature where the bot automatically buys an upgrade when you have enough cookies for it and if you don't it prints out "You don't have enough cookies!" but for some reason the script will always print out that even if I have enough cookies. Does anyone see the problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')
cookie = browser.find_element_by_id('bigCookie')
while True:
      cookie.click()
      try:
            product = browser.find_element_by_class_name('product unlocked enabled')
            product.click()
      except NoSuchElementException:
            print('You don't have enough cookies to buy that!')
            continue
```

Comment: Probably the problem is with `browser.find_element_by_class_name('product unlocked enabled')`. Try finding by link text or xpath or change "class name" to something like `product.unlocked.enabled`.

Comment: I thought the same thing at first but when you have enough cookies to by an upgrade its class name changes to "product unlocked enabled" so I am more or less sure that isn't the problem here cause I fiddled around with it a lot...

Comment: my Firefox shows class `product unlocked enabled` only for `cursor` and `product unlocked disabled` for other products but I can click them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because find_element_by_class_name converts name to css selector.
So if your name is "product unlocked enabled", selector will be ".product unlocked enabled". But right css selector for this case is 
".product.unlocked.enabled" because this element have multiple class name which consists from 3 class names: 'product', 'enabled', 'unlocked'. 
You should use name like "product.unlocked.enabled" or for example "unlocked.enabled" which also correct because this element still have classes "unlocked" and "enabled".